# Distance controlled led

Tags: c++, arduino, distance, sensors

I'm trying to create a distance controlled LED that turns off at a certain distance. I'm using an arduino Leonardo and a distance sensor. At the moment when I plug in my board the led stays on permanently and doesn't turn off when the distance reduces. Please can you tell me what needs changing in order for this to work?

```
const int TrigPin = 2;
const int EchoPin = 3;
float cm;
int ledPin = 12; //define ledPin12 is the output port of led’s level.
int val = 0; //define original of val.
void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(TrigPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(EchoPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); //set ledPin output
}
void loop()
{
    digitalWrite(TrigPin, LOW); //Low-high-low level sent a short time pulse to TrigPin
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(TrigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(TrigPin, LOW);
    cm = pulseIn(EchoPin, HIGH) / 58.0; //Echo time converted into cm
    cm = (int(cm * 100.0)) / 100.0; // retain two decimal places
    Serial.print(cm);
    Serial.print("cm");
    Serial.println();
    delay(1000);

    val = analogRead(EchoPin); //get the value from sensor
    if(val<=1)
    {
        //512=2.5V, if want the sensor be more sensitive, increase the number, or lese low the number.
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); //when the value of val is less than 512(2.5V), light up led lamp
    }
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a debugger. What errors are you getting? Have you tested your logic using constant values? Why do the comments not seem to match the code?

Comment: It's not giving me any errors, it just Isn't functioning as I would have hoped.

Comment: what do pulseIn() and analogRead() do? Is it valid to call both on the same pin in quick succession? What is your output for the cm printing?

Comment: @TonyPark These are both standard Arduino functions.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the sensor is similar to an SRF005. You should include that detail in your question.

The trigger looks okay, but there is no harm in pulsing a little longer, say 20 us, to make sure. The capturing of the echo looks right, except that that datasheet I found says to divide by 5.8, not 58.0, and the return value is an unsigned long, not float..

But you shouldn't be using `analogRead()` on the echo pin. It will be 0 at that point. Rather, you already have the distance in the `cm` variable.

(There are sensors which use pin voltage to indicate distance as well, but they don't have trigger and echo pins. Which kind are you actually using?)

```
void loop()
{
    int cm = 0;

    digitalWrite(TrigPin, LOW); //Low-high-low level sent a short time pulse to TrigPin
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(TrigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Change to 20
    digitalWrite(TrigPin, LOW);
    cm = (int)(pulseIn(EchoPin, HIGH) * 10 / 58); //Echo time converted into cm <<<<<<<<< 5.8 ????
    Serial.print(cm);
    Serial.print("cm");
    Serial.println();


    if(cm < 50)
    {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); 
    }
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }

    delay(1000);
}
```